# Internet access using mobile phone in Argentina

Tags: cellphones, internet, argentina

Considering the mobile Internet in Argentina, I have two related questions:

- Is there a mobile provider that offers a (pre-paid) sim to access the mobile Internet for a reasonable rate?
- How good is the mobile internet coverage in Argentina? I'm especially interested in the provinces Salta, Buenos Aires, and Santa Cruz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a good  detailed article regarding Mobile Internet in Argentina.

http://www.robhyndman.com/2011/01/04/mobile-internet-access-in-argentina/

*Note the author mostly stayed to urban areas.*

He also added an update at the bottom you might miss

> Quick update: I’ve been dazzled by how popular open wifi is in
>   Argentina, even in small towns. Bars, restaurants, malls – lots of
>   places, and often unexpected places, offer free, abundant wifi. Funny,
>   because in Canada, where our data rates are wildly expensive, free
>   open wifi is not nearly as easy to find.

Comment: is there anything which is not restricted for 48 hours ?

Answer (score 1):

I used Movistar all over the country. You can buy a sim (pronounced seem) in a Movistar office for 30 peso. Once its activated you have to then go buy credit from a shop or kiosk, I would just go into a shop and say "recharge" and point at my phone, they will then ask for your number,best to have it written down to show them, and the amount of credit you want. It currently cost 2.45 peso per 15mb.

I had to set a APN up called 'internet' with a username and password also of 'internet' to get these to work.

Comment: Thank you for sharing with us. I was advised to use Movistar as well, but I did not like the signal quality.