# Internet access using my notebook in Argentina

Tags: internet, argentina

I'm Brazilian and I was talking to my girlfriend in Argentina and she uses Movistar, but I did not like the quality of the signal, but it's already something.

I would like to know how to get out of the airport in Buenos Aires and access the internet through my notebook anywhere in the country. I use linux in my notebook, work by myself with technology and didn't want to get disconnected.

### EDIT

I was talking yesterday with my girlfriend that lives in Argentina and she tells me that Movistar Claro have a USB Modem for that. (4G Claro in Brazil is awful so I think that could be awful in Argentina as well).

- I using a notebook DELL Debian 8 Linux

Please I'd like to know about your experiences traveling using your notebook to Argentina

References:

[Internet access using mobile phone in Argentina](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21353/internet-access-using-mobile-phone-in-argentina)

[Modem USB Novatel Ovation MC950D en Ubuntu/Linux](https://quilombo.wordpress.com/2008/01/20/modem-usb-novatel-ovation-mc950d-en-ubuntulinux/)

Comment: Are you looking to use a Sim card with your device, or trying to use wifi?

Comment: I think that exists a USB modem of Movistar, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of the coffee shops and restaurants in the largest cities of Argentina have free Internet access (password protected). You just have to order something and ask them for the Internet password.

Other than that you can bring an unlocked smartphone with you and buy here a pre-paid line with Internet access, then use your smartphone as a Wi-Fi hotspot to which you can connect your laptop.

I work many times "on the go" in coffee shops or other places in Buenos Aires, and I either use the available free wi-fi connection at the place, or use my smartphone as a Wi-Fi hotspot to connect my laptop through the smartphone data connection.

Comment: Thanks but I also think to live there, so I suppose I should use a WIFI modem.